# Is it true that if an action verb or stative verb is immediately followed by a preposition it is intransitive?

Tags: prepositions, verbs, transitivity

"If an action verb or a stative verb is immediately followed by a preposition, it is intransitive."

For example:

> I left for work.
> I was thinking about you.

Comment: Joshua, what do you think an intransitive verb is? How do your sentences match that definition? Please edit your question to show us what research you've done yourself, why you think the quote might not be true, and how you have analyzed your two example sentences so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you accept "He gave to Sally a ring" as grammatical English? It is not the usual order, but it is understandable. The verb "gave" is transitive.  The usual, unmarked order is "He gave a ring to Sally."  The unusual order may be preferred to give "end weight" to a long or complex object.

Also some sentences that seem to contain prepositions are better analysed as containing a phrasal verb:  "He tore up the paper"  Here the verb "tear up" is transitive.

An intransitive verb has no direct object.  Usually the direct object immediately follows the verb, but in some cases it can be placed after an intrusive prepositional phrase: "He put, on the floor, his grandmother's felt hat that she'd received for her birthday forty years ago."  (This long and heavy object phrase might be better at the end like this)

Comment: OK, I see what you mean haha. Just to clarify though, in the two examples I gave, are the verbs transitive or intransitive? I'm 99% sure they're intransitive, but...